# How long can I stay per entry with a single-entry Vietnam e-visa vs a multiple-entry e-visa?

Tags: visas, multiple-entry, vietnam, e-visas

I will apply for a Vietnam e-visa in the coming days but I'm having trouble understanding some of the details due to the plethora of unofficial sites not saying the same thing, and the official site not being very clear IMHO.

I know there are single-entry and multiple-entry options. And the price doubles from $25 USD for the former to $50 USD for the latter.

I can see that multiple-entry visas are valid for 90 days.

I can't seem to find for certain whether that's per entry or per the whole visa.

But I'll probably opt for the single-entry e-visa this time. In this case I'm still not clear on whether I can get 90 days with a single-entry visa or whether that's only an option with the multiple-entry visa, as some sites seem to imply.

Can anybody find an official source with a clear answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [official website](https://evisa.xuatnhapcanh.gov.vn/trang-chu-ttdt) says:

> Vietnam E-visa is valid for maximum of 90 days, single or multiple entry.

Can't be clearer than that I think. 90 days is the validity of the visa (total), and if you want to go in and out, you select the multiple-entry option; if you want to stay for up to 90 days in one go, you can select single-entry.

Comment: Damn I must've missed the clear bit while reading too many pages full of unclear bits!

Comment: Happens to the best of us!

Comment: Just to confirm, I applied for a single-entry e-visa, calculated the 90-day span exactly myself, and received an e-visa for exactly that for the $25 USD fee.